# Unable to resume activity when try to setImage for imageview

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Thanks for Attention

i am still stuck when try to set image for image view onresume activity

```
public class CardActivity extends Activity {

public static class CardType {
    public static String Owner = "owner";
    public static String VIP = "vip";
    public static String Staff = "staff";
    public static String Normal = "white";
}

private static ViewConfiguration vc = null;
private static int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

Context context;
ErrorHandle errHandle = null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    if (MainActivity.MainPreferences == null) {
        MainActivity.MainPreferences = new AppPreferences(context);
    }
    // Halt all the autosaved function
    MainActivity.MainPreferences.putAutoSavedData(false);

    errHandle = new ErrorHandle(this);

    // Set the screen layout first
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Show the content
    assign_layout();

    setup_Gesture();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onResume() {
    errHandle.showDebugToast("CardActivity.onResume", "Start");
    super.onResume();
    assign_MembershipData();

}
@Override
public synchronized void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    errHandle.showDebugToast("CardActivity.onDestroy", "Start");

    super.onDestroy();
}

private void assign_layout() {
    String cardTypeText = MainActivity.MainPreferences.getCardType();
    TextView fullName_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFullName);
    TextView cardNumber_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCardNumber);
    try {
        if (cardTypeText.equalsIgnoreCase(CardType.Owner)) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_owner);
            fullName_text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            cardNumber_text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else if (cardTypeText.equalsIgnoreCase(CardType.VIP)) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_vip);
        } else if (cardTypeText.equalsIgnoreCase(CardType.Staff)) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_staff);
        }  else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_card);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO e
    }
}

private void assign_MembershipData() {
    errHandle.showDebugToast("CardActivity.assign_MembershipData", "Start");
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    // Get the message from the intent
    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    String fullName = MainActivity.MainPreferences.getFullName();
    String cardNumber = MainActivity.MainPreferences.getMemberNumber().replace("-", " ");
    String email = MainActivity.MainPreferences.getEmailAddress();

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "cynthe.ttf");  

    TextView fullName_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFullName);
    fullName_text.setTypeface(font);
    fullName_text.setText(fullName);
    ImageView qr_code_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qr_code_image_barcode);

    qr_code_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_archi2);
    TextView cardNumber_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCardNumber);
    cardNumber_text.setTypeface(font);
    cardNumber_text.setText(cardNumber);    }

private void setup_Gesture() {

    // Gesture setup
    vc = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
    SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
    SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();

    // Gesture detection
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new CardGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };

    ImageView imageCard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageCard);
    imageCard.setClickable(true);
    imageCard.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
}

public void close_VirtualCard() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

    // Reactivate all the autosaved function
    MainActivity.MainPreferences.putAutoSavedData(true);

    finish();
}

class CardGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                errHandle.showDebugToast("CardGestureDetector.onFling", "Right to Left");
                close_VirtualCard();
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                errHandle.showDebugToast("CardGestureDetector.onFling", "Left to right");
                close_VirtualCard();
            } else if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                errHandle.showDebugToast("CardGestureDetector.onFling", "Up to down");
                close_VirtualCard();
            } else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                errHandle.showDebugToast("CardGestureDetector.onFling", "down to up");
                close_VirtualCard();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
}}
```

and i get this error

```
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {package.name/package.name.CardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2127)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at package.name.CardActivity.assign_MembershipData(CardActivity.java:136)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at package.name.CardActivity.onResume(CardActivity.java:84)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1199)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5237)
04-17 11:37:15.562: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
```

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/SplashScreen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="fill" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCard"
        style="@style/SplashScreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/auto_small_text"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/member_card_vip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textFullName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="@string/membercard_fullname"
            android:textColor="@color/LightGoldenrodYellow"
            android:textSize="@dimen/vcard_text_normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCardNumber"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="@string/membercard_number"
            android:textColor="@color/LightGoldenrodYellow"
            android:textSize="@dimen/vcard_number_normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/qr_code_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is work well in high spec device but i got error when i try to run in the low memory device

Comment: what is the 136th line of `CardActivity` class?

Comment: qr_code_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_archi2);

Comment: does your activity layout contains `Imageview` with id `qr_code_image_barcode`?

Comment: of course i ve checked on it

Comment: call assign_layout(); in onResume method.

Comment: Since your are assigning different layour based on the condition so you have to check which is the current layout and does current layout contains that `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize all your layout after calling `setContentView(R.layout.name);` method in your `assign_layout()` method.

Just change your method as below:

```
private void assign_layout() {
    String cardTypeText = MainActivity.MainPreferences.getCardType();
       try {
        if (cardTypeText.equalsIgnoreCase(CardType.Owner)) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_owner);
            fullName_text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            cardNumber_text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else if (cardTypeText.equalsIgnoreCase(CardType.VIP)) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_vip);
        } else if (cardTypeText.equalsIgnoreCase(CardType.Staff)) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_staff);
        }  else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_card);
        }
    TextView fullName_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFullName);
    TextView cardNumber_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCardNumber);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO e
    }
}
```

I would suggest you to initialize your views inside your `if` loop only because you are inflating different layouts based on condition. So your views will be always initialized based on the layout which is inflated. So remove all the views initialization from `assign_MembershipData()` and move it into the `assign_layout()` according to the layouts in which your views resides.

Comment: there is no problem with others view, i just have a problem with imageview. i ve tried with your suggest too but get the same error

Comment: In which layout your `ImageView` resides? @FransTuaniRyersonSiburian

Comment: @FransTuaniRyersonSiburian You need to call first `assign_layout()` method in your `onResume()` before  `assign_MembershipData()` method.

Comment: @GrlsHu i ve tried
FYI this code work in phone but not in tab

Comment: @FransTuaniRyersonSiburian What issue you are facing in tab?

Comment: Its getting nullpointer error that means its not able to find one of your view in method `assign_MembershipData` in `onResume` method.